# Update the url and save the axios response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, redirect, axios

I have my code to accept an input from the user (Device name) and once I click on View , I send an axios request to a service and get a response from it and using that response, I show a design for that device name.
This functionality works fine.

```
 <input type="text" id="devicename" onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)}><br> />
 <Button text='View' variant='primary' type='submit' onClick={this.onDeviceNameEntered} />
```

On clicking the View Button, the onDeviceNameEntered is called, where I send

```
onDeviceNameEntered = async () => {
    this.setState({ enteredDeviceName: true });
    const DeviceName = this.state.devicename;
    // an axios post request is built by calling buildRequestToGetData(DeviceName) 
    const responsedata = await axios.request(buildRequestToGetData(DeviceName)).then((response) =>
      (response.data),
    ).catch((error) => {
      if (error.response && error.response.data) {
        this.setState({ error: true });
      }
    }
    );
  //code to display the data in responsedata
  };
```

If I need the url to change from current url:
https://www.example.com/
to
https://www.example.com/DeviceName
after the axios response is obtained for the input device name, so that when I share the url with someone else, he would be able to see the response data for a particular device without typing the device name and clicking the submit button again.
i.e. if I need to get my url updated and need to share the url after the response is obtained. Is there any function that would help me do it in Javascript?

Comment: Are you using React router?

Comment: No, since there is only one webpage in my application I am not using React router.
Also, after clicking the View button, it displays the response data in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the pathname of the url using `window.location.pathname`.

In your example that will return `/DeviceName`. Remove the forward slash from the pathname string and set the pathname to devicename in state.

```
state= {
 devicename: removeForwardSlash(window.location.pathname)
}
```

`removeForwardSlash` would just be a function to implement removing a forward slashing or parsing the pathname however works best for you.

Use componentDidMount to check if devicename exists in state and then make your api call using `this.state.devicename`